# How to run artisan schedule in browser?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Help me please.
How to run this command:

```
php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

in browser (example.com/runschedule) ?

Laravel version: 5xx

I have tried

```
Route::get('/runschedule', function () {
    Artisan::call('schedule:run');
    return back()->with('status','Cron complete!');
});
```

but it is not working. The page shows

> (Whoops, looks like something went wrong.)

Comment: Enable error reporting and check what went wrong.

Comment: certainly you can call it on the browser.   check you laravel error log.  show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You command is running fine, and probably your redirect back should work as well, what you probably have is a problem in your scheduled commands:

```
/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // This is the scheduled command

    $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();
}
```

As people said here, edit your .env file and enable debug `APP_DEBUG=true`, also, take a look at your logs: `storage/logs/laravel.log`.